# Windows 10 C# UWP App Icon/Name Issues

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

[Icon for UWP not showing when searching for app in Start Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ojW1.png)

[Live Tile showing the wrong name and no icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpgNA.png)

[Settings from Visual Studio Asset Generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LARYF.png)

[Picture of the "Short Name" textbox filled in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq2wK.png)

I'm having an issue with a C# UWP Windows App I'm developing, the icon isn't showing up on the Tile and also when searched for in the Start Menu

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Identity Name="a4c700f9-b389-48e0-897f-165ed80428aa" Publisher="CN=*PERSONAL NAME REMOVED*" Version="1.0.10.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="a4c800f9-b689-48e0-897f-165eb80428aa" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>*NAME REMOVED* Testing Tool</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>*PERSONAL NAME REMOVED*</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="*NAME REMOVED*_Testing_Tool.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="*NAME REMOVED* Testing Tool" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="*NAME REMOVED* Testing Tool" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:LockScreen Notification="badge" BadgeLogo="Assets\BadgeLogo.png" />
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" Square310x310Logo="Assets\LargeTile.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\SmallTile.png" ShortName="*NAME REMOVED* Testing Tool">
          <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
          </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\*NAME REMOVED*_white_logo.png" BackgroundColor="#002395" />
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialCommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a chat with a Microsoft employee online, this appears to be a lesser known bug, it only affects some machines with certain software/hardware configuration. After testing my issue on two other surfaces with the same setup the issue persisted, however when testing on a fresh install of Windows 10 on a HP laptop, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your Package.appxmanifest and go to Visual Assets, you will see show name with check boxes. Check off appropriate box next to your assets
and for icons you can check the icons image size !

[image]

hope this will help you ...

Comment: In the 'Picture of the "Short Name" textbox filled in' image, this shows those options ticked :(

Comment: inside the short name box enter your app name and check the icons image sizes

Comment: the image sizes are perfect, I used the VS generator, and the checkboxes are checked

Comment: Tell me what files you require and I'll upload them :) I thought I had covered everything in my post

Comment: all project if you can ... and you can remove your codes just keep the main page and the appxmanifest file....

Comment: I have created a new project, the same behavior can be seen:
http://www.filedropper.com/test_26
I'm using VS2017 if that makes a difference?

Comment: @NickGarfitt Your project worked well on my side. See [Screenshot1](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnHINRJFF52Tviina) & [Screenshot2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnHFJpdxo3Aa68j3E). This issue might be related to your system environment. Because when I first open your project, my antivirus software reports that there is a virus.

Comment: That's quite strange!! I will take a look thank you for checking this out, it works perfectly on yours.

Edit: Just disabled my antivirus and rebooted- still the same issue pertains. Maybe it could be my Windows 10 environment, it's a Surface Pro 3, Windows 10 Pro, 64bit

Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz, 2301 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

Comment: @NickGarfitt yes your project works fine for me just try to update your `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` to the latest version and if that not works try to reinstall your windows 10 maybe you have some problems ... hope this will help you

Comment: @louay https://i.imgur.com/91OjH0T.png :( Already up to date, can't reinstall W10 as this is a business laptop/tablet I use

Comment: @NickGarfitt I'll upload one project by me and you test it if that's fix your problem you can go on and if it's not I think you should try one of those reinstall your vs 2017 and if that's not work either you must reinstall your windows I'll upload a project in a minute

Comment: hope this will work for you [my project](http://www.mediafire.com/file/cz214bkm7cyo2u0/TEST.rar) if not I'm sorry about that just try to reinstall vs 2017 or repair it, and if that not works you have to reinstall your windows...I've tried my best hope I help you enough

Comment: Appreciate your efforts thank you but still not working, must be either my VS install or Windows 10, will try to compile with an older VS.